# Find first empty class div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type='text' class='inptag' id='inptag'>

<div class='tagstore' id='tagstore'>
    <div class='tagsingle'></div>
    <div class='tagsingle'></div>
    <div class='tagsingle'></div>
    <div class='tagsingle'></div>
    <div class='tagsingle'></div>
</div>
```

**js**

I need to find first empty `tagsingle` and make its text as `a`.

```
$('#inptag').keypress(function(e) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var a = $(this).val().trim();
        // here I need something like:
        $('.tagsingle:first-empty').text(a);
    }
});
```

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and [empty](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) separately as

```
$('.tagsingle:empty:first').text(a); //get empty first and then first
```

**Demo**

```js
$('#inptag').keypress(function(e) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = $(this).val().trim();
    // here I need something like:
    $('.tagsingle:empty:first').text(a);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='inptag' id='inptag'>

<div class='tagstore' id='tagstore'>
  <div class='tagsingle'></div>
  <div class='tagsingle'></div>
  <div class='tagsingle'></div>
  <div class='tagsingle'></div>
  <div class='tagsingle'></div>
</div>
js
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `:empty` selector then the `first()` method like :

```
$('.tagsingle:empty').first().text('a');
```

So you're filtering first the `empty` elements with class `tagsingle` then you're getting the first occurrence from returned result.

```js
$('#inptag').keypress(function(e) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = $(this).val().trim();

    $('.tagsingle:empty').first().text('a');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='inptag' id='inptag'>

<div class='tagstore' id='tagstore'>
  <div class='tagsingle'></div>
  <div class='tagsingle'></div>
  <div class='tagsingle'></div>
  <div class='tagsingle'></div>
  <div class='tagsingle'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first()` and `filter(':empty')`:

```js
$('.tagsingle').filter(':empty').first().text('a');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tagstore' id='tagstore'>
  <div class='tagsingle'></div>
  <div class='tagsingle'></div>
  <div class='tagsingle'></div>
  <div class='tagsingle'></div>
  <div class='tagsingle'></div>
</div>
```